# Changing in between Document Libraries to Bulk Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, modern-experience, metadata-navigation

We use classic experience for our document library but there is no bulk edit.
Is it possible to just change to new expereince for one day and use the Bulk Edit uption to change the metadata of a lot of files.

We want to return again to the classic expereince because of the Metadata Navigation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your request correctly, switching to classic view can be done by adjusting the setting of the library in Advanced Settings - Classic Experience (last setting on the page)

Comment: We have classic view already but I can't BulkEdit Metadata. So I wondered if its possible to change to Modern Expereince  do the BulkEdit and then swtich back to Classic Expereince again .

Comment: what do you mean by bulk edit? is it the view 'Quick edit'? and why you cannot use this button in classic view? is it grayed out? try using Internet explorer instead of other browsers

Comment: I can click mutiple files and change their content type and everzthing. have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wReS3oBIOE&lc=z23nujcbhp3vvtgau04t1aokg3mz2ejgsajip5ksxec3rk0h00410.1559068019549127

Comment: the video shows the modern view, so why you want to switch back to classic?

Comment: The users of our sharepoint are used to classic and the metadata navigation and the ability to have webparts. I just need to change a lot of content types and using the bulk edit feature in modern expereince would save me  many hours

Comment: so my reply stand correctly, to switch to classic you need to go into the library settings - advanced settings